# share screenshots with Dropbox does not work

Tags: macos, dropbox

the automatically share screenshots with Dropbox does not work for me in 10.9. I’m not sure what to do, already installed the latest version of Dropbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't have this active on my Dropbox account by default but of you I tried it out on my 10.9 system.

It doesn't work for me either and this could either be because of the OS or Dropbox. What I suspect is that OS X won't allow the changing of the screen shot location from a third party app.

What you can do as a work around is the following:

Launch Terminal and use the following syntax:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /path/
```

For example, if I want to have the screenshots appear in a specific Dropbox folder, you would use:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Dropbox/Pictures/Screenshots
```

Log out or restart your Mac and take a screenshot. This should now automatically place the image in the new folder and thus Dropbox is syncing.

For additional fun check out: http://secrets.blacktree.com/?showapp=com.apple.screencapture